# Is this computation erroneous?

Tags: calculus, mathematica

The solution to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{100}}{2^{n/100}}$ should be $\infty$ because $n^{100}$ grows much faster than $2^{n/100}$

But if you input

`lim(n^100/(2^(n/100)),n,inf)`

into Mathematica, [you get that the limit is 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28n%5E100/%282%5E%28n/100%29%29,n,inf%29) as `n` approaches infinity. Any way to reconcile these results?

Comment: Yes, because $2^{n/100}$ actually grows much faster than $n^{100}$.

Comment: How is that true? At $n=1$, $2^{n/100}$ is the 100th root of 2, which is slightly over 1; $n^{100}$ is 1. At $n=2$ $2^{n/100}$ is the 50th root of 2, which is also slightly over 1; $n^{100}$ is enormous.

Comment: The question is not how they compare at $n=1$ but when $n$ is *large*. Plug in $n=10^{1000}$. How do they compare now?

Comment: By the time that $n=100$ such that we are not dealing with purely fractional exponentiation in the function $2^{n/100}$, $n^{100}$ is already $100^{100}$ which is *clearly* bigger than $2^1$.

Comment: And how does that make any difference? Consider the following formulation of your problem: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{2^{n/k}},$$ where $k>0$ is fixed. If $k=100$ we obtain your problem. Does it seem absurd if $k=1$ or $k=2$?

Comment: @Fantini I think you mean $n/k$ in the exponent of 2 in the denominator.

Comment: @qaphla Right. Thanks! I've edited.

Comment: @franklin 100 $\neq \infty$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that $n^{100}$ is bigger than $2^{n/100}$ when $n=1$ or $100$, or even $1000$, but try $n=1{,}000{,}000=10^6$.  You get $n^{100}=10^{600}$ while

$$2^{n/100}=2^{10{,}000}=(2^{10})^{1000}\gt(10^3)^{1000}=10^{3000}$$

Similarly, $n=1{,}000{,}000{,}000=10^9$ gives $n^{100}=10^{900}$ versus $2^{n/100}\gt10^{3{,}000{,}000}$.

Convinced yet?

Answer (score 3):

Use L'hopital rule $100$ times, it's evident that $n$ in numerator vanishes while denominator will still be $2^{n/100} \times $ some factor.